# Should I drop temp table in this scenario?

Tags: sql-server, web-services, azure, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure called in a .Net webservice that works like this (pseudo-code):

```
CREATE PROC SomeProc AS
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '#temp%')
        DROP TABLE #temp;

    CREATE TABLE #temp (...);
    /* lots of logic here */

    -- clear up
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '#temp%')
        DROP TABLE #temp;

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '#temp%')
        DROP TABLE #temp;
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
END CATCH
```

The proc is always accessed via the same connection to the database (as defined in a config file).

Somebody has raised a concern that if the webservice, and thus the procedure gets called twice in quick succession, the there is a danger that the temp table for the second call would be deleted by the first call.

Is this correct?  I thought SQL Server was synchronous, so that two procedures couldn't be called at the same time and SQL would queue the requests?  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348428/explicitly-drop-temp-table-or-let-sql-server-handle-it) seems to suggest I am doing the right thing but the multi-thread answer concerns me.  Any clarification would be helpful please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local temporary (#) tables are session scoped, there is no way that some other session could interfere with a temp table created in your session.

If you do a select on sys.tables in tempdb, you will see that every temp table is suffixed with a session identificator.

Also, there is no need to explicitely drop a temp table in stored procedure, SQL Server will do the automatic cleanup, and also cache the metadata for possible performance benefit.

Comment: Thanks. How about if the same webservice (and same user using the service) called the proc twice in succession?  Would that then require the table to be dropped to prevent cross-use of the temp table, i.e. would the session remain in scope?

Comment: No, it's different temp table every time a procedure is executed.

Comment: Read the section on temporary tables here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx).

TRUNCATE TABLE #temp;

Comment: Is that better or worse than what I'm doing now, and why please?

Comment: It is a little bit different from DROP TABLE. Temp table it is a tables in a session. In your case it is a better way.
TRUNCATE TABLE removes all rows from a table, but the table structure and its columns, constraints, indexes, and so on remain. To remove the table definition in addition to its data, use the DROP TABLE statement.